# Octave docs not present

Tags: osx-lion, octave

```
octave:1> doc fflush
```

> info: /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.6.3/share/info/octave.info: No such file or directory

I'm not sure what I've done wrong with my installation, but I get the msg above when attempting to find the documentation (`help fflush` works fine). Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: how and where did you install Octave?

Comment: `which octave` yields `/usr/local/bin/octave`, installed via homebrew

Comment: I don't know about mac. If you had built it yourself, could have been that you disabled the documentation at build time. With a package manager... check whether homebrew has a separate package for the documentation. Something like `octave-doc`

Comment: Thanks.  `brew search octave-doc` yields nothing, but that was a good idea.  I have no idea either to be honest with you.  It was either install it via brew or go through the 5 year process of finding/installing all the dependencies.  :)

Comment: there's a bunch of other package managers for Mac that have Octave. See [Octave's wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X). Taking a quick look at the other package managers, it seems that they all have separate packages for docs.

Comment: Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll mark it correct if I can validate an installation of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Mac OSC. If you had built it yourself, could have been that you disabled the documentation at build time. With a package manager... you already checked that it does not have a separate `octave-doc` package.

There's a bunch of other package managers for Mac that have Octave. See [Octave's wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X). Taking a quick look at the other package managers, it seems that they all have separate packages for docs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it with manually decompressing the corresponding deb archive to the respective place of the brew installation:

Download the deb from here : http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/quantal/all/octave-info/download

```
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir doc
cd doc
ar -x ../octave-info_3.6.2-5_all.deb
tar xzf data.tar.gz 
cd usr
find . -name '*.gz' -type f -exec gunzip "{}" \;
cd ..
cp -r share /usr/local/Cellar/octave/3.6.4/
cd ~/Downloads
rm -r doc
```

You have to adjust the octave version numbers to match the most recent and your brew cellar of course.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. This solved the problem for 4.2.0 as well.